# Как использовать готовую ML модель на Python (sklearn), когда вся логика реализовывается на другом языке?

Tags: машинное-обучение, развертывание, scikit-learn, pickle

У меня модель. Это `LGBMClassifier` с `sklearn`.
С помощью `pickle` я сохранил модель в формате `.sav`.
Это модель трейдинга, которая будет использоваться для торговли американскими акциями.

Сейчас стоит задачи использования модели для реальной торговли. Реализовывать код хотят на `.net`.
Т. е. получается, что модель создана на `Python`, но весь код, кроме самой модели будут реализовывать на другом языке.

Я хочу узнать, как можно использовать готовую Python модель в production, когда вся логика, кроме самой модели реализуется на другом языке. Можно ли такое сделать?

Никогда не занимался вопросами деплоя моделей. По этому, за любую информацию по этому поводу буду благодарен. Хочу хотя бы понять, в каком направлении двигаться чтобы сделать деплой модели.

Если есть какие-то другие пути решения этого вопроса или же описанный подход не имеет смысла, тоже буду благодарен за комментарии.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В java есть `Java Native Interface`(JNI) который позволяет вызывать функции **C++** кодом и наоборот. А в **С++** уже можно написать функцию импорта python библиотеки.
Вот ссылка на [пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/440470/).